# compare individual point to the point preceding it

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (call it df) with columns 'u' and 'time', and I am conditionally coloring points in the plot of this dataframe by comparing them to quantiles.

I currently have working

```
col=ifelse(df$u > quantile(df$u,.98),'orangered2', 'black')
```

But I would also like to add a condition which says: if the preceding point was in the .95 quantile, and the current point is also at .95 quantile, then color the points yellow. Essentially, if two or more points in a row are greater than the .95 quantile, then highlight these points. If it easier to write a comparison between the point and the point that follows, than that should be basically the same thing (i think).

in other notation:

```
if y(x)>quantile(.98): color red
else if (y(x)>quantile(.95)&y(x+1)>quantile(.95)): color yellow
else if (y(x)>quantile(.94): color purple
```

I tried using lag() as i saw described in another question about comparing values to the values that precede them

```
col=ifelse(df$u > quantile(df$u,.98),'orangered2', 
           ifelse((df$u > quantile(df$u,.95))&(lag(df$u) > quantile(df$u,.95)), 'gold1', 
                  ifelse(df$u > quantile(df$u, .94),'darkorchid3','darkgrey')))
```

but if i try this same thing without the lag(df$u) part, i get the exact same graph, which is not what i want. I read ?lag and it doesn't seem like this is what i want, but i was just trying to use the other question's answer.

(also, this is my first question on stack, so comments on how to improve my question are greatly appreciated)

Thank you

Comment: `stats::lag` is built for time series data, but `dplyr::lag` might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Regarding how to improve the question -- try including a sample `data.frame` with dummy data and another `data.frame` showing the expected results / desired outcome.

Comment: Something like `set.seed(47); df = data.frame(u = rnorm(100))` is a great way to share data easily and reproducibly. Just for the illustrative purposes you might want to lower your threshholds as well so that, using small-ish random data there is a good chance of two points in a row falling outside the quantile threshhold.

Comment: For example, with 100 random normal points, you could still keep the 0.98 for red, but maybe use 0.80 for yellow and 0.75 for purple.

Comment: @Gregor okay i will add some data to the question. and thank you, how can I tell R that I am using the dplyr lag and not the stats lag?

Comment: Either load `dplyr` (`library(dplyr)`) or call it with double colons, `dplyr::lag()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most efficient way, but here's an illustrative example.

```
# simulate data and load `dplyr`
set.seed(47)
df = data.frame(u = rnorm(100))
library(dplyr)



df$color = with(
    df,
    ifelse(
        u > quantile(u, 0.98),
        "red",
        ifelse(
            # for yellow, we have a complex condition
            # u must be greater than 0.8 quantile
            #                 AND either one before or one after must also be greater than 0.8 quantile
            u > quantile(u, 0.8) & (lag(u) > quantile(u, 0.8) | lead(u) > quantile(u, 0.8)),
            "yellow",
            ifelse(u > quantile(u, 0.75), "purple", "gray80")
        )
    )
)
```

Though I don't love the colors you've picked, you can verify with

```
plot(df$u, col = df$color)
```

If I squint just right, I can see the yellow.

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly. I have also changed colors to eye-ball friendly ones: orangered2, gold1, darkorchid3, and darkgrey, all on a black background.